# How to resolve Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RCTToastAndroid.TOAST')

Tags: react-native

[image]

I want to run a react-native app. Before, it runs normally. An then when I add a sound and I run it again it show Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RCTToastAndroid.SHORT')

I already open another stackoverflow question like this but it not resolve my problem

Comment: Can you share some code of what you are exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: when I search in VScode, I dont find any RCTToastAndroid, or ToastAndroid, or RCT. And I have so many classes. So I confused about what code should I show

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error, even without any code from you, I have some assumptions.

You are probably trying to implement Android Toast in your app. 
In the react-native docs there is an example of how to do it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android#the-toast-module) and you are getting an error because of it.

Please Provide the full code where you are implementing it so we can get an proper solution.

By what you posted in your answer, there is some error in implementing Android's Toast.

OR

You have the Toast module implemented correctly, but your are in an IOS device and in you can't use Android's Toast in IOS.

If this is your case, you can try implementing something different to display and use react native [Plataform.select](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html) to render the Toast in Android and something else in IOS.